# input angular.moment Error: [$injector:unpr] angular.js:9400

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, angularjs

I build android with IONIC framework, and i try use type="date" in my project to search but i know field in date like this `2017-5-10T17:00:00.000Z`. I used angular.moment to filter date be like this `2017-5-10`. if i use angular.moment field  in datepicker was correct but my app error and i look in console have error `Error: [$injector:unpr] angular.js:9400`

in index i add some script like this

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.5.1/moment.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.min.js"></script>
```

in my controller

```
$scope.trip.start = moment($scope.trip.start).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
```

and this my html

```
<label class="item item-input">
  <span class="input-label">Start</span>
  <input type="date" ng-model="trip.start" value="{{ trip.start }}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd">
</label>
```

datepicker work like i want but my app in side menu error 
[image]

my side menu not like this, please help me how to solve my roblem